# Java LinkedBlockingQueue: check if element already exist

Tags: java, collections, java.util.concurrent

I need to add on a blocking queue only elements are not already added on it previously.

So, currently code is:

```
public void enqueue(Collection<Audit> audits) {
    audits.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
    this.pendingAudits.addAll(
        audits
    );
}
```

I need to add each element of `audits` only if each element doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do this.pendingAudits.removeAll(audits) followed by this.pendingAudits.addAll(audits)

Comment: use a hash map to store the audit exist or not

Comment: the operation to check duplicates is usually time consuming. Consider using specialized collections types like java.util.TreeSet.